# jQuery - bizarre toggle behaviour with recent version

Tags: jquery, html, cdn

This problem really had me confused for quite a while, and the solution ended up being forcing an older version of jQuery to be loaded from the Google CDN.

I had built a menu with this structure:

```
<ul>
<li class="top-nav">
<a href="#">Top Item One</a>
<ul class="sub-nav hidden">
<li>Sub Item One</li>
<li>Sub Item Two</li>
<li>Sub Item Three</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li class="top-nav">
<a href="#">Top Item Two</a>
<ul class="sub-nav hidden">
<li>Sub Item One</li>
<li>Sub Item Two</li>
<li>Sub Item Three</li>
</ul>
</li>

... etc ...

</ul>
```

I have a very simple toggle function, so that when the 'top-nav' is clicked, the sub-nav slides down and appears.

```
$('li.nav-top>a').toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.nav-sub').slideDown(100);
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).siblings('.nav-sub').slideUp(100);
});
```

The incredibly confusing thing is, that with the latest version of jQuery, this code causes all of the `top-nav` list items to collapse and disappear, I have no idea why as it's just a toggle and it isn't even targeting the top level items!

(the site is www.sjofasting.no)

Comment: `toggle()` is **deprecated** ???

Comment: Oh wow,that was stupid of me.

Comment: In future if something breaks when you upgrade read the [upgrade guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) and release notes.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had been using the google CDN version's latest 1.x release, so it broke without me even realizing it. Good to know I should be careful about not specifying exact jQuery versions! I initially thought I had somehow messed up the code during a recent backup/sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes in the selectors and the classes in the markup are not the same, `toggle()` is deprecated, and you should probably prevent the default action of the anchor to avoid scrolling to the top ?

```
$('li.top-nav > a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
           .next('.sub-nav').slideToggle(100);
});
```

Comment: It was already deprecated quite some time ago; now it's completely removed.

Comment: Yes, in 1.9 it's removed, and using it will just toggle the elements visibility.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, code was matched on site, just incorrect here. Thank you for providing an alternative to toggle though as there was no information on what to do to replace it on the jQuery site.